# Save the data only when submit

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

im dealing with problem that makes me crazy :(,
i have a edit user page form writted in AngularJS 2,
the page show the data of the user and when the user clicks on "edit"
i used ngModel to set the data in inputs,
when the user change the inputs data it change it in the regular page (even if he not click submit), well its clearly right , that's how work two way data binding.
but how can i do that only when the user clicks on submit,than the data will be saved ?
i already tried to use [value] but it only shows and not update when i send a parameters to a function in the component, thanks!

```
<!--main-->
<div class="main-container">


  <div class="wrapper">

  <div class="user-profile">
          <div class="title">
              {{title}}
          </div>

        <!--  change password  section -->
        <div *ngIf="action == 'password'">
            <label for="title">סיסמא ישנה</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="הכנס את סיסמתך הישנה" [(ngModel)]="loggedInUser.oldPassword">

            <label for="title">סיסמא חדשה</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="הכנס את סיסמתך החדשה" [(ngModel)]="loggedInUser.newPassword">

            <label for="title">סיסמא חדשה שנית</label>
            <input type="password"  class="form-control" placeholder="הכנס את סיסמתך החדשה שנית" [(ngModel)]="loggedInUser.newPasswordRepeat">

        </div>
        <!-- end -->

        <div class="form-group" *ngIf="!action">

              <label for="title">שם משתמש</label>

              <p *ngIf="!userInput">{{loggedInUser.username}} <a (click)="openUserInput()"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></p>
              <div class="input-group" *ngIf="userInput">
              <input type="text" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="loggedInUser.username" style="float:right;">
              <button class="btn btn-default" style="float:left;" (click)="saveChanges(loggedInUser.username)">שמור</button>
              </div>

              <label for="title">סיסמא</label>
               <br />
              <p><a [routerLink]="['password']">שנה סיסמא <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></p>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group" *ngIf="!action">
            <label for="title">שם מלא</label>
            <p>{{loggedInUser.firstName + ' ' + loggedInUser.lastName}}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" *ngIf="action == 'edit'">
            <label for="title">שם פרטי</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="loggedInUser.firstName" placeholder="שם פרטי">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" *ngIf="action == 'edit'">
            <label for="title">שם משפחה</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="loggedInUser.lastName" placeholder="שם משפחה">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" *ngIf="!action || action =='edit'">
              <label for="title">תאריך לידה</label>
              <p *ngIf="!action">{{loggedInUser.birthDate | date:'dd/MM/y'}}</p>
            <div *ngIf="action == 'edit'">
              <input type="date" [(ngModel)]="loggedInUser.birthDate" value="{{loggedInUser.birthDate | date:'dd/MM/y'}}" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" *ngIf="!action || action =='edit'">
              <label for="title">אימייל</label>
              <p *ngIf="!action">{{loggedInUser.email}}</p>
              <div *ngIf="action == 'edit'">
              <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="loggedInUser.email" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    <div *ngIf="action == 'edit'">
      <button class="btn btn-primary button" (click)="saveChanges()">ערוך פרטים אישיים</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default button" [routerLink]="['..']">חזור אחורה</button>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="action == 'password'">
      <br />
      <button class="btn btn-primary button" (click)="savePassword()">שמור סיסמא חדשה</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default button" [routerLink]="['..']">חזור אחורה</button>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!action">
      <button class="btn btn-primary button" [routerLink]="['edit']">עדכן פרטים אישיים</button>
    </div>

  </div>

    <div class="left-side">
      <img src="https://scontent-lht6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13620270_1084305151608899_3512014032800491903_n.jpg?oh=55fa5de5ed0729dd1200611bce28e91b&oe=58B03EAE" class="img-circle">


  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: plz post code what you done

Comment: `ng-model` will always be two-way. You could use indirection; use an `ng-model` variable in your controller to handle the state, then on clicking submit the state variable could be accessed there and then, saving it to wherever you want.

Comment: what you mean "use ng-model variable in your controller" @Defiant

Comment: Your controller file, where you defined `loggedInUser`. The variable is `firstName`, so `loggedInUser.firstName`.

Comment: i know i can do that,but my problem is that i dont wanna the user to view the changes if he click go back (in page) then the user will see the changes even if they didn't actually saved and sent to the server, the object is atcually changed...

Comment: Firstly, differentiate between _page state_ and your _client-side data_. Your _page state_ will be updated as the user enters new information, e.g. with `ngModel`, `loggedInUser.firstName` will be updated as the user enters the information. The problem is, you display the user's first name using this variable... instead, you should use a separate store to keep this, and **only** update it when your `saveChanges()` function receives a successful response from the server. When it does this, you can simply do something like `myDataStore.firstName = loggedInUser.firstName`.